# Как собрать Scala проект с зависимостями?

Tags: docker, scala, package, sbt

Интересует как можно собрать Scala проект с зависимостями?

sbt package собирает проект, но без зависимостей, и я не могу понять как их подцепить( Требуется получить на выходе jar файл со всеми зависимостями. Если при этом оттуда будет вырезан код который не используется - будет вообще хорошо.

И так же очень интересно как его потом можно развернуть в docker-контейнере.

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20938177/4827341

Comment: Прошу прощения что долго не отвечал.
По поводу sbt-assembly - я про него знаю, но он не хочет мне собирать проект. Делаю всё по инструкции, в итоге говорит что есть конфликты по зависимостям, как их убрать - я нигде не нашел(

Comment: исходя из того, что на более общий вопрос вам ответ так и не дали, мне кажется, имеет смысл задать новый, более конкретный вопрос: что пытались сделать, какую ошибку получили (см. [mcve]).

Answer (score 3):

Я использую sbt-native-packager для пакования приложения с зависимостями. Там есть таска stage которая пакует все пакеты в **target/universal/stage/libs** и создает bash файл в **/target/universal/stage/bin** для запуска

Для того чтобы разворачивать в докере я создаю dockerfile в репозитории проекта. Чтобы создать образ я использую скрипты которые копируют собранное приложение и dockerfile в одну папку. В dockerfile получается что то типа:

```
FROM kondaurov/jre
ADD app /app
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/bash", "/app/bin/myapp"]
```

Далее эту папку я делаю в tar.gz и закидывают в nexus чтобы можно было скачать релиз от куда угодно

чтобы создать образ просто запускаю:

```
docker build -t myApp .
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, обязательно попробую ваш вариант.
А по нексусу - я так понимаю он не обязателен если я пользуюсь docker registry?)

Comment: nexus использую в качестве удаленного файлового хранилища, да, он не обязателен. каждый ищет удобный вариант под себя.

Comment: Настроить собственный docker-registry у меня не получилось, там нужно запариваться с ssl сертификатами, https, и прочее. Мне проще скачать и собрать образ в самом докере уже. Может есть проще способ, но я пока остановился на этом варианте

Comment: Хм... а не подскажите как настроить нексус что бы скала проект использовал его как прокси? Я так понимаю вы его именно так используете кроме как просто файловое хранилище? Просто я вроде его подключил - но фактически через него файлы не проходят(

Comment: Я не публикую там артефакты, просто храню готовые бинарники. Как прокси он работает для npm и bower пакетов

Answer (score 0):

assembly плагин прикрутите

> org.apache.maven.plugins
>       maven-assembly-plugin
>       3.1.0